# Azure CosmosDB Document - Bulk Deletion

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, databricks

Recently, I have asked to delete few million records from a total of 14Tb of Cosmos Db data.

When I looked into the internet, I found a stored proc to do the bulk delete and that works based on partition key.

My scenario is, we have the 4 attributes in each document.
1. id
2. number [ Partition Key]
3. startdate
4. enddate

The requirement is to delete the documents based on startdate.

Delete * from c where c.startdate >= '' and c.startdate <=''

The above query goes through all the partition and deletes the records.

I also checked by running the query in Databricks to take the whole CosmosDB records in a temp Dataframe and add TTL attibute and then upsert to Cosmos DB again.

Is there a better way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, bulk deletion has the methods listed in this [article](https://tekaris.com/blog/azure-cosmos-db-bulk-delete-with-ttl/).

[image]

Since your data is very huge,maybe bulkDelete.js is not suitable any more. After all, SP has execution time limit.In addition to the solution described in your question, I also suggest that you could use SDK code to encapsulate a method by yourself:

Set the `maxItemCount = 100` and `EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true` in your query request.Meanwhile, you could get `continuation token` which is for next page data.  Process the data in the batch and maybe you could get some snippet of code from [.net bulk Delete Library](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-bulkexecutor-dotnet-getting-started/blob/master/BulkDeleteSample/BulkDeleteSample/Program.cs) (`GeneratePartitionKeyDocumentIdTuplesToBulkDelete` and `BulkDeleteAsyn`)

Comment: Thanks Jay, is using SDK would be of less cost compared to running a databricks and adding TTL and upserting the records ?